# Would have usage in sentence

Tags: word-usage

Is it a right sentence
  "They would have found it recently"

This sentence   "They would have found it recently"  can be used to explain in such scenarios were information provided  is quite contradict or advanced than mine

So in order to justify myself,I could use this sentence...

Comment: "They would have found it recently." is a perfectly valid sentence. You can even use it as a question with the question mark.  On  the other hand, the rest of your question is quite incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*They would have found it recently* only really works in particular contexts. For example, in response to a question or postulate about something being found but the ***when*** is unknown, with limitations on the timing.

Example:

> When did the police locate your car?
>
> They would have found it recently, otherwise I would have been notified earlier.
>
> When did they discover the software bug?
>
> They would have found it recently, because it was only in the newspaper today.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid sentence fragment, in the past conditional.  For example,

"There was an expedition into the cave last week.  Had there been a dragon in there, then they would have found it recently."